# Camel - How to change destination(to) when processing a file(processor)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a spring boot application and with camel I read a file using FTP, I process the file and move that file to another location, my problem is that I need to change the destination depending of the file name. I read that I can use "toD" and use property placeholder to change the destination dynamically but I don't know how to set that value from the processor or is even possible to do that?,

Here is my main class:

```
@Component
public class Controlador extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    Procesador objProcesador;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("ftp://user@ip:21?password=mypassword&passiveMode=true&delete=true").streamCaching().convertBodyTo(InputStream.class).process(objProcesador).to("file:C:\\Users\\juan.gaytan\\Desktop\\prueba2");
    }

}
```

And here is my Processor class:

```
@Service
public class Procesador implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use *Simple* as explained [here](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html).
An example would be to set the destination in exchange header as

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("uri", destination);
```

and use in route as below

```
<toD uri="${header.uri}"/>
```

Comment: You can just set a header with the key `Exchange.FILE_NAME` with the name of the file you want, and the file endpoint will use that. See the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/file2